# Index of a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

If G is finite group, then every subgroup of G is finite. If we take normal subgroup H of G and look at it's index in G. That index has to be finite, if I am thinking right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because if $G$ is finite and $H$ is its subgroup, the index of $H$ is simply $$\frac{|G|}{|H|}$$

Comment: Thank you. :) And, because H is normal subgroup, index of H is equal to number of elements of a quotient group G/H?

Comment: @Cece Correct. In general, the index is the size of the **set** $G/H$, but if $H$ is normal, $G/H$ is in fact a group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it is also true if $H$ is not normal.

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then its index is defined as the cardinality of the set $P=\{aH\mid a\in G\}$.

Observe that $P$ is a *partition* of $G$ and consequently has a cardinality that will not exceed the cardinality of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

When $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, you can define two equivalence relations on $G$, that I usually denote with $\sim_H$ and $_H{\sim}$:
\begin{align}
x\sim_H y &\quad\text{if and only if}\quad xy^{-1}\in H \\
x\mathrel{_H{\sim}} y &\quad\text{if and only if}\quad x^{-1}y\in H
\end{align}
Proving that these are equivalence relations is a good exercise in applying subgroup properties.

The main property of these equivalence relations are, denoting by $[x]_{\sim}$ the equivalence class of $x$ under the equivalence relation $\sim$,

1. $[1]_{\sim_H}=H$
2. for every $x\in G$, the map $h\mapsto hx$ is a bijection $[1]_{\sim_H}\to[x]_{\sim_H}$; in particular, $[x]_{\sim_H}=Hx$
3. $[1]_{_H{\sim}}=H$
4. for every $x\in G$, the map $h\mapsto xh$ is a bijection $[1]_{_H{\sim}}\to[x]_{_H{\sim}}$; in particular, $[x]_{_H{\sim}}=xH$

In particular, if $G$ is finite, all equivalence classes under $\sim_H$ have the same cardinality as $H$, so the number of equivalence classes is $|G|/|H|$. This number is the *index* of $H$ in $G$.

Note that this is a proof of Lagrange's theorem that $|H|$ divides $|G|$.

In the same fashion, all equivalence classes under $_H{\sim}$ have the same cardinality as $H$, so it's immaterial whether you use one or the other equivalence relation for defining the index.

The subgroup $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $\sim_H$ is the same relation as $_H{\sim}$, because this reduces to the statement “$xH=Hx$, for all $x\in G$”.